# parsing first entry of a find call in perl?

Tags: perl, bash, find

I need to get an example file file from a `find` command in a Perl script to create another system call afterwards. For some reason, the `find` command gets stuck when I call it from the script. Here is what I need to do:

```
my $search_dir = "/something/like/this/??/??/??";
# the triple '??' are needed here
my $cmd = "find $search_dir -name \"\*.$var1.token1.$var2.ext\" | head -n 1";
my $first_example_file = `$cmd`; chomp $first_example_file;
```

This gets stuck when I run it through Perl, it never finishes executing the command, whereas the constructed $cmd runs in no time if I copy+paste it and run in in my bash terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck", exactly?

Comment: it never finishes executing the command

Comment: Try executing `$cmd` directly from the command line.

Comment: Works for me.
BTW, if you want to escape the asterisk in the shell, you have to use double backslash in double quotes.

Comment: A similar example (changing the `$search_dir` and the name of file to search) returns with a correct result in my system. Are you patient enought :-) ?

Comment: I just tried a simple example, and it worked for me on an old RHEL 4 system. My command was a little simpler: `find $search_dir -name \"\*.sh\" | head -n 1";` Perhaps your $var1 and $var2 variables aren't what you expect them to be? I would add a few print statements around these lines to inspect what everything is. Print out $cmd, $var1, and $var2 to make sure they are what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/File/Find.pm) perl module for finding files. If you would like to use `bash's find` in your `perl` then you might have to use `$(..)`  in your command.

I am not in to `perl` … just trying to help out.

**Update:**

As stated in the comments by `Rohaq` you can also use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)

Comment: File::Find is good, though I prefer File::Find::Rule for setting up searches before running them.

Link: http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm

Comment: Thanks @Rohaq … have added your suggestion in the answer. Hope thats ok.

Comment: File::Find::Rule will only return after all results are found, though. I dislike File::Find, but I think you can exit prematurely (by using `die`?).

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager globbing (shell metacharacter expansion) is involved. But regardless, try and chop the command up. Does it work without the pipe? What about without the ?? in the pathname? What happens if you prepend 'echo' ("echo find ...")? Still hanging?  Then you can try it under perl -d  - the debugger; perldoc perldebug is your friend.